# iOS launching Safari app from your app without passing url

Tags: ios, openurl

I am launching my app through Safari, that works fine. After doing some task I need to launch Safari back with the current page. I can open safari after passing some url but that I don't wan't to do.
So is there a way through which I can just redirect my app to Safari without opening a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Once your app is launched you can't close it unless the user wants to do so. You can launch Safari again only by opening a new tab with an URL from your app.